# Cascading DropDownList in Custom Editor Web Part using SharePoint 2010

Tags: web-part, custom-web-part-property

Does anybody know how to achieve a cascading dropdownlist in an editor web part?

Comment: Do you mean a 'Content Editor WebPart'? Is so, than you have to write your own JavaScript (try it with jQuery).

Comment: sorry, custom editor web part

Answer (score 5):

Check out Marc Anderson's [SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com) library, there is a [cascading drop down operation](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24%28%29.SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns&referringTitle=Documentation).  You could also achieve that functionality through InfoPath forms, but not in the web enabled forms I believe.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are talking about a custom editorpart (toolpanepart).  I've done this before using dropdownlist controls and implementing icallbackeventhandler to ajax load the cascading dropdowns.  The only gotcha I ran into was a pagevalidation error.  I got around that by using the Page.ClientScript.RegisterForEventValidation for my new values of the dropdownlist before my partial postback was complete (in the GetCallbackResult method).

If you don't need dynamic cascading dropdowns, as in the data will always be the same, then you can create an htmlgenericcontrol that has all of your html data in it like you normally would on a html page.  I don't think you have to worry about naming conflicts as much with this because you can only have one toolpart pane open at a time.

Comment: do you have sample code?

Comment: For which solution i outlined above?

Answer (score 0):

Try [RichControls for Sharepoint 2010](https://github.com/AnfiniL/richcontrols), an open source project hosted github. [image]